# Creating Macro to print selected cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I am trying to record a `Macro` to print selected cells then return the worksheet to its original format.  I am hiding columns B through H, printing `A7:I68`.  While recording the Macro the print comes out correct.  Once saved it only prints column A7:A68, does not include column I.

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Columns("B:H").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("A7:I68").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$7:$I$68"
Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
Columns("A:I").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-72
Range("A10").Select
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
    False
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Edit the question and insert your Macro

Comment: Go into the macro, and press F8. See what happens, and press F8 and see what happens, step by step. Maybe it's not hiding the columns properly. Maybe it's not selecting the print area - stepping into a macro is a decent troubleshooting step.

Comment: Selkie, Thank you for your suggestion, I tried it but got the same result. The print area is set up correct in the macro but the output is still only column A. ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$7:$I$68". Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Tina I would like to suggest VBA code to print Not one but Multiple Selections,, this will copy range to print make sheet paste there, show Preview, Print & finally delete that sheet.

```
Sub Print_MultiSelection()

Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, rngArea As Range

Set rng = Selection

Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

For Each rngArea In rng.Areas rngArea.Copy Destination:=ws.Range(rngArea.Address)

ws.Range(rngArea.Address).Value = rngArea.Value

Next 

rngArea ws.PrintPreview

ws.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:= False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ws.Delete Application.DisplayAlerts = True

rng.Parent.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick Q, have you got some hidden area in your ActiveSheet? If you specify the PrintArea in the PrintOut line may work. i.e.

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Columns("B:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$7:$I$68"
ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, PrintArea:="$A$7:$I$68"
Columns("A:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-72
Range("A10").Select
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False
```

On top, if you want a more "sophisticated" version ;) try below, hope it helps. The goal addition was to handle **hidden** range.

```
Sub PrSelRng()
    Dim prRng As Range
    
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    On Error Resume Next

    Set prRng = Application.InputBox("Select the range to print", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If prRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Printing canceled.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not prRng.Worksheet Is ActiveSheet Then
        MsgBox "Please select a range on the active sheet.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = GetVisibleRange(prRng).Address
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False

End Sub

Function GetVisibleRange(rng As Range) As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim visibleCells As Range

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
            If visibleCells Is Nothing Then
                Set visibleCells = cell
            Else
                Set visibleCells = Union(visibleCells, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    If Not visibleCells Is Nothing Then
        Set GetVisibleRange = visibleCells
    End If

End Function
```